# How to jump from one html file to another in Onsen UI (both html files' content begin with <html>)

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

I have two html files, both file's content begin with tag html, not begin with tag ons-page or ons-navigator.

One is index.html, in this file I have some ons-page(such as user login, signup, forget password),
The other is main.html, the main business logic UI/logic.

The question is:
When user login process finished, How can I jump from index.html to main.html? And How can I pass some data from index.html to main.html.

```
window.open("main.html", '_self');
```

The code above works on PC browser only, not Android.

```
window.url = "main.html";
```

The code above not works on both PC browser and Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Onsen UI navigation patterns if your file doesn't contain `ons-template` or if the content is not spread in different HTML files. Is there any issue in using `ons-template` or dividing the content in multiple files?
Moreover, which element are you using to perform the page navigation? If you are using `ons-navigator` with `var='myNavigator'`, you can execute a function which contains the following instruction:

```
myNavigator.pushPage('main.html', {param1: 'bla'})
```

Comment: Thanks :) I have understood this question. Yesterday I thought should divide login process and main business logic to two separate html files, but indeed it's not necessary. When logged in I can use resetToPage() to shift into the main business logic and totally destroy the login process related pages.